Can immovable alien artifact be exploited to create infinite energy source for humanity?
Say in given solar system exists an alien/magic artifact that is immovable in point of reference of the center of mass of the star.
Obviously it defies laws of physics. There must be a force that is acting on it, drawing it away from the star. This force must have a source of energy, thus the object has an infinite energy source at it's disposal.
How to harness such energy source? There must be a way of exploiting it and transform it to something that humanity can actually use.
I'm interested in answers that allow to draw infinite energy out of it. Conceptually you can probably use it to decelerate all celestial bodies in given planetary system and gain their respective potential energies, but you're gonna run out of planets fairly quickly.
To visualize it better:

let's assume it's solar system
the object's shape is a disk 1km thick and radius of 1000km
it has sunward and voidward sides
it is positioned on invariable plane
the distance from the Sun is 10AU
it's strong enough that nobody was able to deform it or chip away a sample. There is no guarantee that it's perfect rigid body, but before trying to nuke it to see if it'd bend maybe let's try to utilize it.


If it is orbiting, then gravity affects it, thus it is not really immovable? :-)

Once something so clearly breaks the laws of physics in so many ways there is little point in asking physics what would happen as physics as we know it would be utterly wrong. So you are on you are own in inventing a new physics.

It's already a perpetual motion machine on its own. To counteract its own star's gravity, it must produce constant acceleration, which thus means it's constantly "moving" in its own reference frame (which is non-inertial due to the force acting on it, which allows it to distinguish motion from stillness).

the sun is orbiting the milky way galaxy at 720,000 kilometers per hour, so its long gone before you can even think of building anything.

@John The question did say "immovable in [the reference frame] of the star" (emphasis mine), so I take that to mean that the object is permanently stationary in the comoving reference frame of the star. Still moving in other reference frames, but the concept of "immovable" doesn't even make sense if you define it to mean stationary in every reference frame.

@controlgroup immovable in refrence to the star and in orbit around the star are mutually exclusive, esspecially since the sun is rotating.  I'm going to vote to close until you better define what your object is doing. you should also define the tech level and the mass of the object.

@John I agree, this question does need more specificity and the object can't be stationary and also in orbit; just pointing out that the specified reference frame was that of the star, not the galaxy.

"We might assume that it's "orbiting"" pretty straightforwardly seems to point out that it actually isn't orbiting. But that doesn't clear up everything :)

Yeah, I thought putting quotes around "orbiting" would be clear enough. Let me rephrase

is a disk (...) and it's "orbiting" in distance of 10AU from the sun.

to

is a disk (...) and it's present 10AU from the sun.


@controlgroup, exactly! So my train of thoughts was: since it's already a perpetual motion machine that has access to infinite energy - how to harness it, turn it into any usable form of energy?
...which would probably turn out being just yet another way of boiling water into steam and running it through turbines...

@John, excellent point about star itself rotating. My first thought was to rephrase it to "immovable in point of referrence of the center of mass of the star". But there is also another option that might be more complex, but yield some interesting results: "immovable in point of referrence of the center of mass of the entire planetary system" (which would make sun wobble a bit from the perspective of The Artifact). But let me settle for the first option for now.

@John, as for tech level, there is none, it's just there. As for mass... I lack the imagination to perform an experiment that would allow to measure mass of such object. But since all the planets are on their usual orbits one thing that can be said for certain is that it's negligible in context of the whole solar system.

the tech level of humanity not the object, you are thw writer you decide the mass.

Moving a Star
There is a term called "bootstrap," based on the anecdote of lifting oneself by pulling on one's own bootstrap, and the same is possible here.
A mass fixed to the alien artifact creates a gravitational field, generating a force that pulls the star closer to the artifact. As the star moves closer, the artifact will move away by the same amount. Gradually, the artifact acts as the arrowhead, and the star as the fletching, accelerating the movement.
If the artifact is orbiting, you can move it in any direction on the orbital plane by making it possible to move the mass, for example, with an elevator. By changing the distance between the star and the mass only during certain periods of the year, you can control the influence on the star.
However, I should emphasize that in either case, this process will take an extremely long time.
